# ignore errors in .hql in oozie workflow

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue, oozie-workflow

I implemented the below statements in `.hql` file and call this file from `workflow.xml` in Oozie. I do not want the Oozie workflow to fail in case that `table1` does not exist i.e to ignore error if alter statement fails. I used `SET hive.cli.errors.ignore=true;`
but this did not help. Any suggestions?

```
SET hive.cli.errors.ignore=true;

alter table table1 SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880692/alter-table-if-exists-t1-rename-to-t2-in-hiveql

Comment: is there any other way ? I am looking for something equivalent to "WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE"

Comment: It's possible in CDH 5.4+ -- refer https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Ignore-errors-in-oozie-workflows/td-p/28828